# A foreach macro with a break or continue statement in C

Tags: c, for-loop, macros, function-pointers

I have several loops across my code, all of them check if a condition is true.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (check_conditition(array[i]))
        break;
    // do something
}
```

So I'd like to wrap this on a macro so I don't have to include the `check_conditition()` on all of them, e.g.:

```
for_each_item(i, array) {
    // do something
}
```

How can I do this? or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Without knowing why you've got this repeating pattern, hard to tell what better alternatives could exist.

Comment: @Mat Perhaps it's worth mentioning that all of the loops perform something different with the available array items.

Comment: Do they modify the array? Could they return/exit? What exactly do they do and why don't you have that abstracted into a function? Macros should be your last resort.

Comment: I agree about that a macro should be the last resort. I thought about using a function pointer. They do not return/exit nor modify the array.

Comment: If they don't modify the array, why are you checking `check_condition` again and again on every loop?

Comment: The only thing it does is to go over the options the user provided via the command line. `check_condition()` verifies that the option supplied by the user is active or not. Could you elaborate how would you  abstract this into a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the `check_condition` in your macro you could add it to the `for` loop condition:

```
#define for_each_item(idx, array)  for (int idx=0; \
                                       (idx<size) && !check_condition(array[idx]); \
                                       idx++)
```

Now you can use the macro as you requested:

```
for_each_item(i, array)
{
    // do something
}
```

P.S. you can replace the `size` with `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` :

```
#define for_each_item(idx, array)  for (int idx=0; \
                                       (idx<(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))) && \
                                       !check_condition(array[idx]); \
                                       idx++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define foreach(x, size, array) for( x = 0; x < size; x++) {\
    if (check_conditition(array[x]))\
        break;
#define endforeach }

int check_conditition(int a){ return 0;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int size = 10;
    int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    foreach(i, size, array)
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    endforeach
    return 0;
}
```